# Trying to Figure out MM/DD/YYYY vs DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: batch-file

I need to figure out if the current date 6/6/2013 is in MM/DD/YYYY vs DD/MM/YYYY format. Hence they are both "6".

What I was going to do was take current date then add 3 days to it and from there I would know which one was the MM field because it wouldn't change. I don't know how to print the date+3 days in batch.  Is it even possible?  Does anyone have any ideas ?  I've been at it for a couple of hours.  I tried to use the GNU date command but I have to specify the output so it's not helpful.. GRR!

Note, this is for WINDOWS. 
Note, the file I'm looking at can't be changed so if the date is 9/9/2013, that is all I have to work with to determine the fields.

EDIT:  I ended up using the following Code:
It's a bit over done but you can see how I basically do it.  The reason why I'm setting the value is because I'm using it in conjunction with the Gnu date.exe command which is really good at provide date based on a particular day. So somewhere else in the script I use it like this:  date.exe --date "Now -90 days" %DATEFORMAT%. I had to ditch the date /T option suggested in another post because that doesn't actually show the correct data for all situations.

```
for /F "skip=1 tokens=3" %%a in ('reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v sShortDate ^< NUL') do (
    echo.%%a|findstr /C:"/" >nul 2>&1 && set DELIM=/
    echo.%%a|findstr /C:"-" >nul 2>&1 && set DELIM=-
    echo.%%a|findstr /C:"." >nul 2>&1 && set DELIM=.

    for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=-/." %%b in ("%%a") do (
        set format=%%b%%c%%d
    )
)

if %DELIM%==/ ( 
    :: US English options 
    if %format%==Mdyyyy set DATEFORMAT=+%%-m/%%-d/%%Y 
    if %format%==Mdyy set DATEFORMAT=+%%-m/%%-d/%%y
    if %format%==MMddyy set DATEFORMAT=+%%m/%%d/%%y
    if %format%==MMddyyyy set DATEFORMAT=+%%m/%%d/%%Y
    if %format%==yyMMdd set DATEFORMAT=+%%y/%%m/%%d 

    :: UK English options
    if %format%==ddMMyyyy set DATEFORMAT=+%%d/%%m/%%Y
    if %format%==ddMMyy set DATEFORMAT=+%%d/%%m/%%y
    if %format%==dMyy set DATEFORMAT=+%%-d/%%-m/%%y

) else if %DELIM%==- (
    if %format%==yyyyMMdd set DATEFORMAT=+%%Y-%%m-%%d
    if %format%==ddMMMyy set DATEFORMAT=+%%d/%%m/%%y
    if %format%==dMyy set DATEFORMAT=+%%-d-%%-m-%%y
) else if %DELIM%==. (
    if %format%==dMyy set DATEFORMAT=+%%-d.%%-m.%%y
) else (
    echo ERROR: System was unable to identify dateformat.
    ping -n 10 -w 1 127.0.0.1 >NUL
)
```

Comment: What format is the date starting in? UNIX timestamp? UTC datetime string? GMT datetime string?

Comment: This is actually an interesting question; on OSX `date` uses a long format. In the end, you need to find the locale of your machine or of the sending program.

Comment: Aiias, I'm using a tool that reads the date so it's just listed in a file as 04/04/2013 so I'm not sure what your question is. I can't change that output.  I was trying to work with it.  One thing I was thinking was scanning the output to see which date field goes over 12 but that would not be foolproof.

Comment: Hi Eric,  Interesting side note.  I was thinking  if I was using OSX or Linux I would be in better shap because I can use the date command in that OS but I don't know if date.exe --date "Now +3 days" +%%-d/%%-m/%%Y  would help, thanks for the comment.  Interesting.

Comment: You'd added info that it is a file you are reading.  Why is it that you don't know the file format?  Does it change?

Comment: Yes.  The tool that generates the list uses the local date settings. For example Sometimes the file is generated in the UK  DD/MM/YYYY and sometimes it's run in the US MM/DD/YYYY etc. etc..  That is the whole problem.  One thing would be to just check which one of these fields is greater than 12 in the results. But the issue with that is: what if there are no dates below it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excuse me, I am a little confused about this topic.

In your original question you needed to "figure out if the current date is in MM/DD/YYYY vs DD/MM/YYYY format" because you was going to "take current date then add 3 days to it". In my first answer I solved both previously requested points (I thought that correctly). However, it seems that the code that you ended up using, solved an entirely different problem: convert the locale date format into a certain particular date format. If this is the new request, then this is my new solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Get the date format
for /F "skip=1 tokens=3" %%a in ('reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v 

sShortDate ^< NUL') do (
   set DATEFORMAT=%%a
)

rem Convert the special case: dd-MMM-yy to +%%d/%%m/%%y
if %DATEFORMAT% equ dd-MMM-yy (
   set DATEFORMAT=+%%d/%%m/%%y
) else (
   rem Convert the rest of cases
   for %%a in ("yyyy=%%Y" "yy=%%y" "MM=%%x" "M=%%-x" "x=m" "dd=%%x" "d=%%-x" "x=d") do (
      set DATEFORMAT=!DATEFORMAT:%%~a!
   )
)
set DATEFORMAT=+!DATEFORMAT!

ECHO %DATEFORMAT%
```

Date management routines are important to me, so I will appreciate it if you may test this solution and report if it correctly converts the date format as you wish, or point to any conversion error. Thanks a lot...

Comment: @MikeQ: Could you take a look at my new answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

to get your current date format in batch try this:

```
@echo off&setlocal
reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v sShortDate
```

..output (may vary):

```
 sShortDate  REG_SZ  M/d/yyyy
```

Comment: +1 short and sweet. fyi, mine output:  sShortDate    REG_SZ    dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: Very good response.  I wish I could give a runner up. Thank you Endoro, the other ans is just a little bit more complete, this is a good answer though. I deeply appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to know the locale date format is using the *input* format of `date` command, that is the same *output* format of `%date%` variable. For example, when I execute `date` in my computer I got this output:

```
The current date is: 06/06/2013
Enter the new date: (dd-mm-yy)
```

So the trick is get the last part `(dd-mm-yy)` and process it:

```
for /F "skip=1 tokens=2 delims=()" %%a in ('date ^< NUL') do (
   for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=-/." %%b in ("%%a") do (
      for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=-/." %%x in ("%date%") do (
         set "%%b=%%x" & set "%%c=%%y" & set "%%d=%%z"
      )
   )
)
echo Day: %dd%, Month: %mm%, Year: %yy%
```

And for the "date+3 days" part, you may convert the date to [Julian Day Number](http://www.hermetic.ch/cal_stud/jdn.htm#comp), add 3 to it and convert the number back to date, but there are simpler solutions:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "skip=1 tokens=2 delims=()" %%a in ('date ^< NUL') do (
   for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=-/." %%b in ("%%a") do (
      for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=-/." %%x in ("%date%") do (
         set /A %%b=1%%x %% 100, %%c=1%%y %% 100, %%d=%%z
      )
   )
)
echo Today's date. Day: %dd%, Month: %mm%, Year: %yy%

set m=0
for %%a in (31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31) do (
   set /A m+=1
   set daysPerMonth[!m!]=%%a
)
set /A yyMOD4=yy %% 4
if %yyMOD4% equ 0 set daysPerMonth[2]=29

rem Add 3 days to today's date
set /A dd+=3
if %dd% gtr !daysPerMonth[%mm%]! (
   set /A dd-=daysPerMonth[%mm%], mm+=1
   if !mm! gtr 12 (
      set /A mm=1, yy+=1
   )
)
if %dd% lss 10 set dd=0%dd%
if %mm% lss 10 set mm=0%mm%

echo Today + 3 days date. Day: %dd%, Month: %mm%, Year: %yy%
```

Comment: Wow Aacini. Brilliance!!! I never thought of poaching the format from the date command.  That would be good enough to tell us the format in a script!

Comment: basically all we need is the results from the first for loop:

Comment: for /F "skip=1 tokens=2 delims=()" %%a in ('date ^< NUL') do (
           for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=-/." %%b in ("%%a") do (
                    echo %%b
            if "%%b" == "mm" set result="MM/DD/YYYY"
        if "%%b" == "dd"  set result="DD/MM/YYYY"
        )
        )
        echo RESULTS:  %result%

Comment: Turns out this doesn't work mm/dd/yy that comes from the date command isn't always correctly reflecting the setting in the registry.

Comment: So? The format of `date` command is the same of `%date%` variable, so it does not matter if the registry have a different format (unless you take the format from the registry instead of `date` command). BTW how did you solved your `date+3 days` problem?

Comment: @MikeQ: Excuse me. Could you give me an example where my method does not give the right answer? That is, the output of both `date` and `echo %date%` commands. This is important for me because I used to provide this answer to other people, and I always have assumed that it is correct. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This is a region insensitive way to get a timestamp - Win XP Pro and above.

Currently there is YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS and YYYY-MM-DD_HH-MM-SS below.  You can change the order of items to get the timestamp you need.

```
:: timestamp YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set dt=%dt:~0,8%_%dt:~8,6%
echo %dt%
pause
```

and one with individual items that can be rearranged:

```
:: timestamp YYYY-MM-DD_HH-MM-SS
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set dt=%dt:~0,4%-%dt:~4,2%-%dt:~6,2%_%dt:~8,2%-%dt:~10,2%-%dt:~12,2%
echo %dt%
pause
```

Comment: Thanks.  I thought of doing something like this.  I actually tried successfully getting the fields with date.exe GNU Linux and with wmic:  for /f "skip=1 tokens=1-6" %%a in ('wmic path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year /Format:table') do set /a month=%%d, day=%%a, year=%%f

Comment: The problem is that the output may have dates like 1/1/2013 or 2/2/2013, etc. There is no way to ascertain the format without getting a date above the 12th. If we were to do it that way.

Comment: The way it is derived in the code I posted, you can always be sure of getting the month and day correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, you can step through the files in the `C:\Windows\Temp` folder until you find one that has a `day` > 12.  Here's a batch file I wrote that demonstrates one way you can do this.  You could take a similar approach on another OS, though I don't know the syntax...

```
@echo off

setlocal

for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4* delims=/ " %%i in ('dir c:\windows\temp /4 ^| find "M   "') do (
  if %%i gtr 2000 (if %%j gtr 12 (set _format=YYYY/DD/MM) else (if %%k gtr 12 (set _format=YYYY/MM/DD)))
  if %%j gtr 2000 (if %%i gtr 12 (set _format=DD/YYYY/MM) else (if %%k gtr 12 (set _format=MM/YYYY/DD)))
  if %%k gtr 2000 (if %%i gtr 12 (set _format=DD/MM/YYYY) else (if %%j gtr 12 (set _format=MM/DD/YYYY)))
  if defined _format goto :TheEnd
)

:TheEnd
echo %_format%

endlocal
```

Comment: Interesting answer!  Thanks.  I think this is a good option as well.  The ans above that I selected used the actual date command which will tell you the date format so you can change it.